# AWS S3api - put-bucket-tagging not placing tags on documents

Tags: amazon-s3, windows-7, aws-cli, tagging

I have an s3 bucket with about 30 documents. I am trying to write awscli to tag each document in the bucket.

I ran the following lines in cmd and both ran without error (and without response, but I think that's normal), however none of my documents have tags associated with them.

```
aws s3api put-bucket-tagging --bucket xxx.yyyy.staticforms --tagging file://tags.json
aws s3api put-bucket-tagging --bucket xxx.yyyy.staticforms --tagging TagSet=[{Key=riskType,Value=myValue}]
```

my json file looks like this:

```
{
  "TagSet": [
    {
      "Key": "riskType",
      "Value": "myValue"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have full admin rights on the account. Anyone know why the tags are not being placed on the documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use put-object-tagging to tag each individual object:

```
aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket xxx.yyyy.staticforms --key path/to/object --tagging TagSet=[{Key=riskType,Value=myValue}]
```

See:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-object-tagging.html

Comment: thanks. there is no way to tag *all* the objects in the bucket? if not, is there a way to write a loop? (I suppose I have to script the loop)

Comment: As you only have a few objects, in PowerShell, something like:

 `aws s3 ls --recursive s3://xxx.yyyy.staticforms/|Foreach {
  $key = $_.Split(" ",[StringSplitOptions]"RemoveEmptyEntries")[3]
  aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket xxx.yyyy.staticforms --key $key --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=riskType,Value=myValue}]'
}`

Comment: interesting. thanks. I don't only have a few objects, but will have several. not 1000s but eventually in the hundreds. Is there any caveat to using this loop based on that info?

Comment: too many aws calls will result in throttling, you could use `Start-Sleep` inside the loop to slow it down if that happens